# Get All products form CS-Cart

Tags: api, cs-cart

I'm trying to get all products from CS-Cart but I can only get all products from one page (24 by default). Anyone knows if there is a cleaner way to do this than to change the items_per_page value to a big number?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `?items_per_page=0`, CS-Cart will list all products for you within a category.

If you want to display a link in the "Items per page" dropdown, it can be a little bit tricky, because you have to write a custom "sorting.tpl" template. Right now, there is no hook you can connnect.

Comment: Thanks, it will be cleaner at least with items_per_page=0 than an arbitary number.